# Ethereum Code bots...Scam or not?

Tags: ethereum, fraud, bots

So new I cant even afford to trade crypto's yet, but looking and learning. I came across some Ethereum Code bot, promising 13k a day etc etc...one of those "sounds to good to be true" things really.
Research is varied in opinions of being a scam or not. The broker is called FTO Capital, unregistered etc...why would a bot need a broker?
Anyone able to say they have used any of these kinds of crypto bots and done ok? As a father of a daughter with a disability I need to play it safe...she needs equipment I simply cant afford at this point in time.

Cheers in advance,
Buck

Comment: *"promising 13k a day etc etc...one of those "sounds to good to be true" things "*... I think you have your answer already. Any legitimate broker I have ever seen would not promise such an astronomical return, I think it is very safe to say you have encountered a scam.

Comment: My thoughts too, hoping someone has tried it/them lol. TY chytrik.

Answer (score 4):

> **promising 13k a day**

It is almost certainly a scam. Stay well away from this.

> **I need to play it safe ... I simply cant afford**

Don't invest in volatile high-risk products such as crypto-currencies.

Answer (score 2):

Ehthereum Code is definitely get rich quick crypto scheme. They are now using fake news to promote this system. There is no technology just random variables that pop up. A quick search for Ethereum Code Scam Gal Gadot reveals how they operate and bait victims.